# How to write iOS backend like (Game Center, IAP etc.) with libGDX?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, libgdx

I write game on libGdx and testing it on Android. All code I write on Java, because libGDX use Java language. How can I write iOS backend on Objective C and link it with Java libGDx core? Is any tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you would accomplish what you are after, the primary problem being the lack of a JVM on iOS.   The recommended way to get a libGDX game to run on iOS is by using MonoTouch from Xamarin.

See [this blog-post from libGDX's Mario on libGDX and MonoTouch licensing](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2846)
Unfortunately, it's not free, nor open-source.  There are some other projects in the pipeline to get a JVM on iOS, via open-source project, like RoboVM, but they aren't fully implemented for libGDX use yet.

Good luck!